# The text "function(e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)}" appears on the product details page in Shopify

Tags: javascript, frontend, shopify

Product pages across our Shopify site display "function(e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)}" above the ADD TO CART box. Not sure where to look for in the project to fix this. Image below shows the text.

[image]

Comment: Js issues that append the code on the website, it might be into theme code or 3rd party app cause it.

Comment: Onkar, I find no clue as to where it is from. How can I figure that out?

Comment: Are able to share the URL?

Comment: https://reflectperfection.com/collections/specialized-sunscreens-after-sun-bronzers/products/stemulation-boost-cregraveme

Comment: Please check the URL above

Comment: I think you need to check and debug the code on theme files called `custom.js` and there is a function name `get_pmm_shipping_text()` that is responsible for this mess. https://prnt.sc/1179wp9

Comment: Yes, custom.js is our file. I know this file. Thanks a lot for your time trying to help me

Comment: code that updates the text after some time is into this file and might be it calculate or parse the wrong output. you need to debug and fix it on the website end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230886/discussion-between-onkar-and-pktg).

Answer (score 0):

bottom of the file.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'`

```
window.KlarnaThemeGlobals.data_purchase_amount=;window.KlarnaThemeGlobals.productVariants=[{"id":20688830464111,"title":"
```

Comment: Charles, I don't see this error nor the line of code in your answer on the product page. Please let me know where you found this

Comment: you will see it when inspect (https://reflectperfection.com/collections/specialized-sunscreens-after-sun-bronzers/products/mdsolarsciences-mineral-creme-spf-30)[https://reflectperfection.com/collections/specialized-sunscreens-after-sun-bronzers/products/mdsolarsciences-mineral-creme-spf-30]